# InventDim from ItemId

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am working on generating a form with fields of dimensions including `Itemid`.

I have a form in which i have only the `ItemId`, I need to find `inventDimID` for it.

How do I do that?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what you want the inventDimID of. What table are you using to get the itemid? What are you looking for (inventtrans table will have the inventdimid of all transactions on a given item).

Comment: I just have a itemid and not any transactiosn

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for here are the dimensions of the item, not necessarily the `inventDimId`. In order to get the dimensions, you could do the following(for the purpose of this example, we have our dimension[1] = Department:

```
static void Job8(Args _args)
{
    Dimension   dim;
    SysDim      department;
    ;
    dim = InventTable::find('3t80').Dimension;
    department = dim[1];


}
```

Comment: basically what u get in the job are ledger dimensions, but i need inventory dimensions

Comment: inventory dimensions do not exist on items, they exist on their corresponding transactions (such as purchase orders, sales orders, journals, etc).

Comment: @TejashreeS this would only really make sense if you are looking for something like on-hand stocks